# Alternate libraries folder locations for Processing (in installation folder?)

Tags: processing

I'm using Processing 2.1.1 on Linux. I am aware that the docs say:

via [Processing 1.0 - Processing Discourse - where's the libraries folder?](http://processing.org/discourse/beta/num_1242005416.html)

> Contributed libraries **must be** [...] placed within the "libraries" folder of your Processing sketchbook

[How to Install a Contributed Library - Processing](http://wiki.processing.org/w/How_to_Install_a_Contributed_Library)

> Manual Install
>
> Contributed libraries may be downloaded separately and manually placed within the libraries folder of your Processing sketchbook.

The thing is - I enjoy running Processing directly from its unzipped folder (without any installation as such); and I actually keep it on a different partition than my "main" partition (which has my home folder, `~`, where `~/sketchbook` is by default created on Linux). Thus, when I install a new library, it ends up being in a different partition than my main program - and I'd like to keep the libraries and the Processing program together.

Is there any way I could achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it turns out there is - there is a folder, `processing-2.1.1/modes/java/libraries/` - and all of the libraries in `~/sketchbook/libraries` can be moved here!

Just note that those libraries, once moved, will not show as "contributed" anymore (in neither "Sketch/Import library..." nor "File/Examples").

Also, if installing from the web via "Sketch/Import library.../Add library...", that installation is likely going to complete in `~/sketchbook/libraries` - so afterwards one would have to close Processing down; move the library folders from `~/sketchbook/libraries` to `processing-2.1.1/modes/java/libraries/`; and then restart Processing again.

Hope this helps someone,
Cheers!